# Should I call an API in my Microservice Or call the API in the filter of my API Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway

**Background**

Each request will run through an API Gateway, each request will have a JWT with custom claim "x-token". Now, this "x-token" is an id that I will use to get the corresponding data in the DB. The "x-token" will be used in about 2 (out of 3) of my microservices.

**Question**

Where should this API call should happen?

My current plans are:

---

**1. [API GATEWAY FILTER APPROACH]**

Add an API Filter in my Spring Cloud Gateway to modify every (GET/POST) request
-Create a Filter and inside the filter perform an api call to get `xTokenObject` associated with the "x-token", and then modify to add the `xTokenObject` in the `@RequestBody` so that on the `Controller` part of my microservice I could easily use it.

*PROS*

- API Gateway will be the only one have access to it
- I can easily use it on the controller function

Sample Code on the Controller of my Microservice where the 'xTokenObject' was added on the Gateway Filter:

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> someMethod(@RequestBody @Valid XTokenObject xTokenObject){
  return ResponseEntity.ok(this.someService.someFunction(xTokenObject));
}
```

*CONS*

- What if there is already a `@RequestBody`? How should I add this `xTokenObject` to that `@RequestBody`? And how can I access it on the Controller of my microservice?

---

**2. [MICROSERVICE CALL]**

Modify the header to add "x-token" in the Gateway Filter and then use it to easily call the API on the `@Service` of my microservice

*PROS*

- Implementation is easy since adding of custom header is easy on the Gateway Filter than modifying the request body

Sample Code on the Service of my Microservice:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {  
    public SomeObject someFunction(String xTokenId) {
    // API CALL HERE USING THE xTokenId
    return someObject;
  }
}
```

*CONS*

- All of my microservice will have a connection to it

**Additional Question and Considerations:**

Which one is faster? Or there is another better way? The data on the Token Data Microservice might contain some sensitive data so it will be encrypted. So it will be on the same DB of my auth-server but different table. I will also consider using Redis to cache these data. I included a photo on this question so you guys have an overview.

[image]

Comment: Did you look into intercepting/filtering? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878326/intercept-http-request-body-in-spring-boot-gateway

Comment: Hi @MuratKaragöz, yes I searched for it and the implementation as well. But base on my possible approach, what do you think is the better one?